# SVG xml:base attribute not working in IE9

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to create an SVG document that includes image tags referencing png files. This works if I include the absolute path of the png in every image tag but if I try putting an xml:base attribute in it doesn't seem to work in IE9. However it does seem to work Firefox and Chrome. Is there a bug in IE or is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:base="file:///C:/SVG/Devices/valves/">
  <image width="40" height="56" x="10" y="10" xlink:href="motorised_valve[purple].gif"/>
</svg>
```

For complicated reasons I don't want to go into here, I can't put the SVG document into the same folder as the images.

Thanks for any help
Mog

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable in your case to embed your PNG images in your document using the `data://` protocol? That would solve your problem, at the expense of potentially making the XML rather large.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not suitable as I need the SVG to be as small as possible. The SVG may need to be sent over an expensive/low bandwidth satellite connection and allowing the pngs (which never change) to be cached separately from the SVG (which does change occasionally) is important.
An additional reason I want to use relative links would be to produce a smaller SVG file as there are quite a lot of different PNGs referenced by the single SVG object.